# what is wrong with my script on duplicate keys?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, key, duplicates

This is an inventory software. it has the field skid number as the primary unique key. i am trying to make an entry if it doesn't exist or update the entry if it does. not working so well l. what am i doing wrong and how can i fix this?  I'm using visual basic 2010. i have tired many alternatives and have failed. Thank You for any help.

Try

```
        strQuery3 = "INSERT INTO inv_by_skid(skid_num, cat, descript, cond, pr_count, cs_count, location, vendor, gender, size_run) VALUES ('" & add_skid_num.Text & "','" & add_category.Text & "','" & add_description.Text & "','" & add_condition_box.Text & "','" & add_pair_count.Text & "','1','" & add_location.Text & "','" & add_vender_num.Text & "','" & add_gender.Text & "','" & add_sizerun_box.Text & "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET  pr_count = '" & temp_prcount_box.Text & "', cs_count = '" & temp_cscount_box.Text & "'"

        SQLCmd3 = New MySqlCommand(strQuery3, dbCon3)

        dbCon3.Open()


        SQLCmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()

        dbCon3.Close()
        MsgBox("Skid Added Successfully!")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failure!", ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: This looks more like VB.NET than VBScript, but well... the problem is not in the VB part, but in the SQL one (one thing is INSERT (new entries) and another thing is UPDATE (existing entries)). A MySQL link you might find interesting: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: You think "not working so well" is a good problem description?

Comment: ty  varocarbas i will look into the link

Comment: Yes, i get the error in the mysql script... a syntax exception. but after looking at the link you provided i still cant see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET
```

...is wrong... it's just

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

You also need to [learn about sql injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and why your code contains massive security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank You!hat fixed it. and i will look into the sql injection method. thanks for the tip..